# Why Is The Remove Button of Internet Options' Content Certificates Greyed Out?

Tags: windows-10, certificate

I want to delete expired certificates from a Windows 10 Home Edition computer. The image below illustrates what I observe.

[image: Windows 10 Home Edition - Internet Options - Content - Expired Certificates - The Remove Button Is Greyed Out]

[image: Windows 10 Home Edition - Internet Options - Content - NON-Expired Certificates - The Remove Button Is Greyed Out]

Why is the "Remove" button greyed out?

Comment: do other certificates behave the same way? is it just the MS Authenticode root or perhaps a select subset of certificates that won't allow you to delete?

Comment: @FrankThomas "do other certificates behave the same way?" I think all certificates. I added an image the shows the same behavior with a non-expired certificate

Comment: @FrankThomas "The certificate can be deleted" why is this "horrible idea"

Comment: because that is a root code signing certificate, and deleting it may interfere with your ability to validate MS signed software. code signing is critical to modern windows OS's. you really don't want to delete it.

Comment: @FrankThomas Txs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the "Remove" button greyed out?

You can only remove personal certificates from Internet Options.

If you want to remove one of those certificates, you can remove the certificate, within the user's certificate store.  **You can simply right-click on the certificate to delete it.**

Of course, if you delete the certificate you have asked about, you will cause yourself a great deal of pain. **You really should NEVER delete any of those trusted certificates.** Expired certificates are not insecure.  The only certificates you shouldn't trust are those that have been revoked.

[image]